# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. (React Native)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to make it so that if an item called `code` is not set in state with redux, it is called from `AsyncStorage` and state is set.

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {handlePhoneNumber, saveCode} from './../../actions/RegistrationActions';

class EnterPhoneNumberScreen extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let code = this.props.registration.code;
    console.log("code is", code);
    if(code){
      // Do nothing
    }else{
      console.log("in the else");
      this.props.getAndSetCode();
    }
  }
}

const getAndSetCode = () => dispatch => {
  console.log("in get and set Code");
  AsyncStorage.getItem('code')
    .then((data) => {
       console.log("data is ", data);
       dispatch(saveCode(data));
       console.log("in getAndSetCode method, Code is ", data);
    })
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators({
    handlePhoneNumber,
    getAndSetCode: () => dispatch(getAndSetCode()),
  }, dispatch)
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EnterPhoneNumberScreen);
```

The console outputs the following:

```
 LOG  code is null
 LOG  in the else
 LOG  in get and set Code
 LOG  data is  3tgvgq
 LOG  in getAndSetCode method, Code is  3tgvgq
```

I know thunk is properly installed because it is running elsewhere in the application.  `saveCode` is just a normal action:

```
export const saveCode = code => ({
    type: "SAVE_CODE",
    payload: code
})
```

And this error appears in the iphone11 simulator:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: In your getAndSetCode you are dispatching `savecode(code)`, but you are importing it as `saveCode`. why?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I am importing it and defining arguments when calling it.

Comment: oh you mean the capitalization? thats a typo in bringing it over to stackoverflow. i'll fix now

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo just fixed typo